# How to modify a specific @type from DefinitelyTyped npm

Tags: angular, types, npm, definitelytyped

I am adding a package(ng2-vis) to my angular 4 project and
need to add a new event name to the type definitions package 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/vis, which it is a dependency from ng2-vis. What I have donde before in a similar case is to fork the repository, modify the files, rename it and then publish it to the npm repository, but in this case @types/vis is inside the DefinitelyTyped repo. I also tried to add the event name modifying directly my node_modules/@types/vis/index.d.ts from the project but its not working (like they recommend here https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/README.md on How can I contribute?->Test)

Answer (score 0):

You can use type augmentation, see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html.

You can do it by creating your own typings file and include this in your typescript compiling. If done correctly, the compiler will merge the declarations.